Number of different ways n can represented as sum of natural number, "irrespective of permutation"
So if theres a natural number $n$, what is the function $f(n)$ such that it gives the number of ways $n$ can be represented as sum of natural numbers irrespective of the permutation of the numbers in the sum.
For eg-
$f(3)=3$, because
$3=1+1+1=1+2$
And $f(4)=5$, as
$4=1+1+1+1=1+1+2=1+3=2+2$

This is called the number of partitions of $n$. There has been a ton of research on it, and that keyword should get you started on an exploration.

This is the partition function; there is no known closed form.
